# How to make a stacked barplot with fill with two numeric variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a stacked barplot in ggplot with two numeric variables in the "fill" area.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Where SEM_NOT is the epidemiological week, n.x is deaths by a disease and n.y is deaths by vaccinated people. I was able to make the plot with Excel but I can't seem to do the same with R. I need something looking like this:

[image]

I've already tried this:

```
mm = melt(ddf)
ggplot(mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=EVTY, fill=variable, y=value), stat='identity')
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please post your sample data as something copy/pasteable, not a picture. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` is a great way to share a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package (it is in `tidyverse`).
2. plot with `ggplot` using `geom_col`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        -SEM_NOT
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(SEM_NOT, value, fill=name)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> There are two types of bar charts: `geom_bar()` and `geom_col()`. `geom_bar()` makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group (...). If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use `geom_col()` instead.
> (from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html )

So this is probably what you are looking for:

```
library(data.table)  # taking `melt` from this
library(ggplot2)

ddf <- data.table(sem.not = 1:30,
                  n.x = sample(5:30, 30, TRUE),
                  n.y = sample(0:3, 30, TRUE))



mm <- melt(ddf, id.vars = "sem.not", measure.vars = c("n.x", "n.y"))
ggplot(mm) +
  geom_col(aes(x = sem.not, y = value, fill = variable))
```